# Redirect URL through AWS Lambda and CloudFront

Tags: node.js, redirect, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudfront

I have a lambda function and I wish to perform a 301 redirect from `https://foo.test.com/user_id/bar/` to `https://app.test.com/user_id/new`

The user's request has an user_id that set as a variable (`${userId}`) and passed to the target URI (`${newUri}`).

The value of the user_id is numbers and letters (`12-qw12`)

I wrote the following code, which sets the ID as a variable and passes it to the Response Headers:

```
exports.handler = function handler(event, context, callback) {
    let request = event.Records[0].cf.request;
    let uri = request.uri;
    let userId = uri.split('/')[3];
    let newUri = `https://app.test.com/` + userId + `/new`;
    const response = {
        headers: {
            'location': [{
                key: 'Location',
                value: newUri,
            }],
        },
        status: '301',
        statusDescription: 'Moved Permanently',
    };
    callback(null,response);
};
```

Unfortunately, I get an empty value from the `${userId}` that passed to the Response headers:

```
https://app.test.com//new
```

If I write the value in the response headers as a string (`value: 'https://app.test.com/12-qw12/new'`) then it works properly.

How can I pass a variable (`${userId}`) to the response headers without getting an empty value?

Answer (score 0):

You can view the Request Event structure
[here:](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-event-structure.html#lambda-event-structure-request)

You can see the actual value of the request URI field by using console.log and checking the respective logs in Cloudwatch.
To print request uri add the folowing the following line before the last two lines in your code:

> console.log(`Request uri is "${request.uri}"`);

Then you can know in which index you read userid value.

Comment: I did this test and saw from which index I read the user_id.
In addition, I have already printed the user_id and the output the correct userid.
The problem here is that the variable comes empty into the response headers.

Comment: Could you type the value that request.uri shows on cloudwatch